# React state is not properly updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a Pomodoro clock and facing an issue when switching back to pomodoro session after an break.

```js
const start = () => {
    //this stop function clears the pre-existing timer if there is any.
    stop();

    setTimerOn(true);

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setDisplayTime((prev) => {

        //onBreak is false by default
        if (prev <= 0 && !onBreak) {
          setOnBreak(true);
          return breakDuration;
        }
        
        // this if statement is not being executed
        if (prev <= 0 && onBreak) {
          setOnBreak(false);
          return sessionDuration;
        }

        return prev - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);

    //save the timer insatance in react state
    setTimer(interval);
  };
```

I am updating the state of onBreak whenver the timer becomes 0. But when I check the state of onBreak in react dev tools then only first if block executed and after that the state never changes. The code went in infinite loop after execution of first if statement and only breakSession is being executed over and over again.

Comment: what are `breakDuration` and `sessionDuration`?

Comment: Looks like onBreak is false always. Could be happening because this function has closed over the initial state and is always using that stale state (onBreak). You probably want to redefine this function too on every render cycle. Or for optimization useCallback with dependency array having onbreak.

Comment: Could you kindly provide us some extra code of the full component if possible. It's hard fully grasp what's going on here. And you should not set time on arbitrary methods. Use them in useEffect (functional component) or componentDidMount(class component). And what is setTimer(interval). let interval = setInterval(...) returns interval id and it's already running!

Comment: I switched to useEffect and it worked seemless. I read some articles which mention the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the function you pass to `setInterval` saves the value of `onBreak` when it was created; it has no way of getting the current state of `onBreak`.  (I'm assuming `[onBreak, setOnBreak] = useState()`.)

One way to pass in changeable state is `useRef`.  Something like this:

```js
const [onBreak, setOnBreak] = useState();

// Create a ref whose value is set automatically to onBreak
const onBreakRef = useRef();
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  onBreakRef.current = onBreak;
}, [onBreak]);

const start = () => {
    //this stop function clears the pre-existing timer if there is any.
    stop();

    setTimerOn(true);

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setDisplayTime((prev) => {

        if (prev <= 0 && !onBreakRef.current) {
          setOnBreak(true);
          return breakDuration;
        }
        
        if (prev <= 0 && onBreakRef.current) {
          setOnBreak(false);
          return sessionDuration;
        }

        return prev - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);

    //save the timer insatance in react state
    setTimer(interval);
};
```

This code feels messy though.  Could you instead do `setOnBreak(false)` in the other code that reacts to when `onBreak` is `true`?  Then the `setInterval` code could unconditionally `setOnBreak(true)` when `prev <= 0`.